# How to delete mirror lines of a text file using bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, mirror

Here is the file:

```
a b
c d
d c
b a
```

The 1st line is mirrored with the 4th line and 2nd line is mirrored with the 3rd line. I just want to keep one of the mirror lines. That means I want to delete line number 3 and line number 4. This is just an example. What I want is to have a code, which figures out the mirror lines and keep only one of them.

Comment: How big is your file, and does it matter what the output order of the fields are at all, so long as the set is distinct? Could there be an `a a` line?

Comment: There are different things `mirror lines` could mean, e.g. order of fields and order of characters within each field, etc. - is `ab cd` a "mirror" of `cd ab` or of `dc ba` or something else? If your real requirement is not just to handle 2 fields in either order then [edit] your question to be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common, idiomatic awk approach is to always arrange the fields in a specific order regardless of their input order and use the result as a uniqueness test array key, e.g. with just 2 fields like in your example:

```
$ awk '!seen[$1>$2 ? $1 FS $2 : $2 FS $1]++' file
a b
c d
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below command:
*This works with GNU awk only*

```
awk '{split ($0, ln, " "); asort( ln ); for( i = 1; i <= length(ln); i++ ) printf("%s ", ln[i] ); printf( "\n" )}' file.txt | sort -u
```

Explanation:
Here I am sorting the lines horizontally, so:

- split ($0, line, " ") --> Will split the line into an array named "ln"
- asort( ln ) --> Will sort this array
- for( i = 1; i <= length(ln); i++ ) printf("%s ", ln[i] ) --> This is used to print the output, but it will be in single line.
- printf( "\n" ) --> This is used with above part to make the output line separated
- Above part will sort the file horizontally, and sort -u will keep only unique values.

Answer (score 1):

These apply to the lines as characters, that means for various number of fields and various length of fields, not only for the provided example.

**1st solution**

```
awk -F "" '{r=""; for (i=NF;i;i--) r=r $i} !seen[$0]++ && !seen[r]++' file
```

Above command excludes symmetrical lines, like: `a a`. We can include them (printing them once) like this:

```
awk -F "" '{r=""; for (i=NF;i;i--) r=r $i} !seen[$0]++ && (!seen[r]++ || $0==r)' file
```

or further improved, adopting the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944093/7589636) of Ed Morton to use one hash and keep always the greater of the two strings (this is alphabetical comparison).

```
awk -F "" '{r=""; for (i=NF;i;i--) r=r $i} !seen[$0>r? $0: r]++' file
```

---

**2st solution**

```
rev file | paste -d \\n file - | awk '!seen[$0]++ && NR%2'
```

Here paste the file with its mirror using newline delimiter, the result has the mirrors as even lines, print uniques only for odd lines (but tested for all), the order of the awk conditions is important because we want to `++` for even lines too.

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack that will probably take forever to run -

```
declare -A item=()
while read -a l
do x="$(printf "%s\n" "${l[@]}"|sort|tr '\n' ' ')"
   item["$x"]=1
done < file
printf "%s\n" "${!item[@]}" | sort
a b
c d
```

The larger and/or more complex the file, the slower this will be, and the more memory it will use. Please prefer Homer's `awk` solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk:

```
$ awk '
!(($1,$2) in a) && !(($2,$1) in a) {    # if neither version is found in hash a
    print                               # output
    a[$1,$2]                            # and hash
}' file
```

Output:

```
a b
c d
```

**Edit:** Another version that reverses the string and can handle strings such as `ab cd` vs. `dc ba`:

```
awk '
function rev(str,    rts) {        # string reversing function
    for(i=1;i<=length();i++)
        rts=substr(str,i,1) rts
    return rts
}
!($0 in a) && !(rev($0) in a) {    # if neither version is found in hash a
    print                          # output
    a[$0]                          # and hash
}' file
```

Comment: Not sure that this is what OP wants: it only works with lines with only two fields. And it also fails for the combination `ab cd` and `dc ba`.

Comment: Yeah, the sample is not unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

First store the file. In one array the values, another the linenumbers.
Run again with the reversed lines and look for equal values.
When the reversed value is in the original set, you know that the mirror has the same linenumber. You can delete the mirror from the original set, knowing that you have just found that the reversed value is in the set too.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=FNR;b[NR]=$0; next}
     $0 in a {delete a[b[FNR]]; }
     END { for (i in a) { print i } }' inputfile <(rev inputfile)
```

Explanation by example:
When you run this with the example file

```
a b
c d
d c
b a
```

the arrays after reading the first file will look like

```
a[a b]=1, a[c d]=2, a[d c]=3, a[b a]=4
b[1]=a b, b[2]=c d, b[3]=d c, b[4]=b a
```

Now the reversed file is processed, first record 'b a' is found, so it must have a mirror. But the file is the reversed original file, so the mirror of `b a` must be on the same line number.
For deleting `a[a b]` you can find the index using `b[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is combining Ed Morton's and Homer's answers to make it work on an arbitrary number of columns while running it all in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) (`gawk` really). Only the first occurance will be printed and it's also using the GNU `asort` extension:

```
awk 'function mkkey(line){
    res="";
    split(line, a);
    asort(a);
    for(i=1; i<=length(a); ++i) res = res FS a[i];
    return res
} !seen[mkkey($0)]++' file
```